# Hovering over the "award bounty" button doesn't show a hand cursor

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, bounty

The title pretty much says it all. Hovering over the button that's used to award a bounty shows the default cursor instead of the hand cursor. All other buttons to the side of the answer use the hand cursor as shown in the following screenshot:

[image: Bounty button cursor]

Just to clarify, the button is clickable and it opens the confirm-dialog normally. The issue is just with the cursor. Also, after the bounty is awarded and the button is no longer clickable, the cursor changes to a "text cursor" (which is fine and expected):

[image: Awarded bounty]

Comment: It's not a link nor clickable?

Comment: @Scratte It _is_ clickable (opens a confirm dialog before awarding the bounty). The lack of the hand cursor is confusing though (it makes you think that it's not clickable).

Comment: Oh! Sorry about that. I only went to test on a post that I have no connection to and found it's not clickable as a "foreigner" on the post.

Comment: How did you make the screenshot though? Just interested :p

Comment: @10Rep If you're on Windows, there are [several utilities](https://superuser.com/q/188788/431599) that provide the option to include the mouse cursor in a screenshot. Then, I simply duplicated the cursor and moved it around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed. You should see the pointer cursor when hovering over the bounty award button when it can be clicked.